# parsec: combine two char parsers into a string

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to write a parser that glues two characters into a string:

```
(<:>) = liftM2 (\a b -> [a, b])
mychar :: Parser String
mychar = (char '\\') <:> (noneOf "u")
```

is it possible to make it more elegant? I am a newbie. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another choice is:

```
mychar = sequence [char '\\', noneof "u"]
```